# Django get the current email of the user by default in a different serializer based on the selected "userid"

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I was wondering what the correct way is to get the current email  of the user by default in a different serializer based on the selected "userid".
I have tried many examples from the [ModelSerializer docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) but without success.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ticker.models import Ticker
from users.models import NewUser
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from alerts.models import SectionAlerts
from users.serializers import UserlistSerializer
from rest_framework.fields import CurrentUserDefault

class TickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticker
        fields = "__all__"

class UserlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = "__all__"

class AlertsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ticker = TickerSerializer(read_only=True)
    email = UserlistSerializer(read_only=True)
    ticker_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    queryset=Ticker.objects.all(), source="ticker", slug_field='crypto', write_only=True
    )
    class Meta:
        model = SectionAlerts
        fields = "__all__"
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ticker.models import Ticker
from django.conf import settings
from import_export.resources import ModelResource
from import_export.fields import Field
from users.models import NewUser
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

class SectionAlerts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # auto increment field
    valuenow = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    valuealarm = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 40,blank=True, null=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(
        NewUser, related_name='userid', 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    email = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(Ticker, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

- **The goal:** anytime that the "Current Value" of a crypto is lower than the previously set "Value Alert", the backend is sending an email notification to the user.
- **The problem:** at the moment all users receive that email notification, while just each individual logged in user that created
  their own alerts should receive it.
- **Question:** how can i add just the email of the user that created the individual alert?

views.py

```
from email import message
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import AlertsSerializer, TickerSerializer, UserlistSerializer
from users.serializers import CustomUserSerializer
from .models import SectionAlerts, Ticker, NewUser
import requests
import logging
from itertools import chain
from importlib import reload
import sys
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .utils import Util
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class CreateSectionAlerts(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        print("New alert is saved")
    serializer_class = AlertsSerializer
    
    
class ListSectionAlerts(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = SectionAlerts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlertsSerializer    
    

    # ------- EMAIL STARTS HERE
    def get_queryset(self):
        print("****ALERTS START get_querysetdavid")
        queryset = SectionAlerts.objects.filter(userid=self.kwargs["pk"])
        
        for b in SectionAlerts.objects.filter(userid=self.kwargs["pk"]):
            # print("b---Print just mail", b.email)
            print("b---Print SectionAlerts", b.id, b.valuenow, b.userid, b.ticker.c_0)
           
            for c in NewUser.objects.all():
                if b.ticker.c_0 < b.valuealarm:
                    print("Alert is achieved and must be sent")
                    email_body = 'Hi ' + c.user_name + ', you received this message because the value of the crypto ' + str(b.ticker) + ' is now ' + str(b.ticker.c_0) +'€.' + ' and reached the alert value of ' + str(b.valuealarm) +'€.' + '\n'+ 'This email confirms this event. \n' + 'Click here https://www.cryptothlon.com to signin in your account and know more. \n' +'\n'+ 'Your Cryptothlon Team'
                    data={'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': c.email, 
                        'email_subject': 'Crypto alert'}
                    Util.send_email(data)
                    print("Email sent")
                    try:
                        record = SectionAlerts.objects.get(id = b.id )
                        record.delete()
                        print("Record deleted successfully!")
                    except:
                        print("Record doesn't exists")
                    # email method ends here 
        return queryset
    # ------- EMAIL ENDS HERE

class DeleteSectionAlerts(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = SectionAlerts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlertsSerializer
```

[image: DRF serializer]

Comment: The screenshot shows a post request for a `SectionAlert` object, `email` is null because you haven't defined a `NewUser` when creating your `SectionAlert`, hence the `email` field contains `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). It will allow you to create a custom field in the serializer. By default `SerializerMethodField` looks for a method `get_<field name>`, and performs the according logic:

```py
from users.models import NewUser


class AlertsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SectionAlerts
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_email(self, obj):
        user_id = self.initial_data['userid']  # get the `userid` from the request body
        user = NewUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)  # fetch the user from DB
        return UserlistSerializer(instance=user).data
```

Comment: Excellent valuable insight. This works perfectly

Comment: Note that it may not be that performant because you're making extra queries. OK if it's not many, but if there are a lot you may find this really slows things down ...

Comment: @michjnich assuming that the OP uses the serializer only once after POST request on `api/sectionalerts/create` it should not cause many troubles and "slow things down".

Comment: No, but I wouldn't like to make that assumption :) It's not wrong, I just thought it worth pointing out there are potential side effects to doing it like that.

Comment: @Ersain do you have any suggestion on why do i receive the error ` 'AlertsSerializer' object has no attribute 'initial_data' ` when i try to call it in the frontend?

Comment: @David are you using the serializer for things other than object creation/update? If so, you won't be able to use `initial_data` property, describe what you are trying to do, and I will edit my post

Comment: @Ersain thanks, i have just added the "goal", the "problem", and the main "question" to the post. I am looking forward to hearing your comments.

Comment: @Ersain i created a new post to try to solve this problem. Do you have any further suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837956/django-add-just-the-email-of-the-user-that-created-an-individual-alert

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the `NewUser` model so not sure exactly what field you need, but you can use dot notation for the `source` of a serializer field.

From DRF docs:

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as URLField(source='get_absolute_url'), or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as EmailField(source='user.email').

See this section of the docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments

Comment: Note that the `email` field is a foreign key relationship to `NewUser` table, and you cannot use primitive data types to serialize the whole object, but in case if you are referencing some field from the object, then you will make extra query to fetch the needed user under the hood, which according to your words can make things slow down

Comment: I seem to have offended you by pointing that out. Not sure why? With this solution you would set the queryset for the view(set) and use `select_related`, which would then pull in the `NewUser` record as part of the same query. Your solution explicitly calls another query for each record. As I say, not a problem if you have a small queryset, but if you need it to scale, not idea.

Comment: @michjnich thanks for your contribution. In fact I didn’t manage yet to achieve my ultimate goal completely. I edited the post to make it more clear. The problem: at the moment all users receive that email notification, while just each individual logged in user that created their own alerts should receive it.
Question: how can i add just the email of the user that created the individual alert? 
Do you have any thoughts on how to solve it?

Comment: @michjnich i created a new post to try to solve this problem. Do you have any further suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837956/django-add-just-the-email-of-the-user-that-created-an-individual-alert

Comment: Only on mobile right now, but will take a look later on if nobody else has answered by then...